# How can i fix "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" issue in my database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I created hotel, room, guest tables. After I created booking table I can't add Foreign key. It makes error.

> Can't create table `hotelbooking`.`booking` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
gId int, 
hId int, 
RoomNo int, 
FromDate Date, 
ToDate Date,
PaymentMethod varchar(100),
FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hotel(hid),
FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES Guest(gid),
FOREIGN KEY (RoomNo) REFERENCES Room(RoomNo),
CONSTRAINT PK_bookingRoom PRIMARY KEY (gId, hId, RoomNo, FromDate)
);


CREATE DATABASE hotelBooking;

CREATE TABLE Hotel (
hId int, 
Name varchar(100), 
Address varchar(255), 
City varchar(200), 
ContactNumber int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (hid)
);

CREATE TABLE Guest (
gId int, 
firstName varchar(100), 
lastName varchar(100), 
Age int,
Gender varchar(2),
Address varchar(255), 
City varchar(50), 
ContactNumber int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);

CREATE TABLE Room (
hid int, 
RoomNo int, 
RoomType varchar(100), 
Price varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hotel(hid),
CONSTRAINT PK_roomId PRIMARY KEY (hid, RoomNo)
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a foreign key across two databases?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a combined foreign key that fits with teh primary key from Room

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
hid int, 
RoomNo int, 
RoomType varchar(100), 
Price varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hotel(hid),
CONSTRAINT PK_roomId PRIMARY KEY (hid, RoomNo)
); 

CREATE TABLE Booking (
gId int, 
hId int, 
rhId int, 
RoomNo int, 
FromDate Date, 
ToDate Date,
PaymentMethod varchar(100),
FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hotel(hid),
FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES Guest(gid),
FOREIGN KEY (rhid,RoomNo) REFERENCES Room(hid,RoomNo),
CONSTRAINT PK_bookingRoom PRIMARY KEY (gId, hId, RoomNo, FromDate)
);
```

Or you define an idex on roomNo

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
hid int, 
RoomNo int, 
RoomType varchar(100), 
Price varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hotel(hid),
KEY(RoomNo),
CONSTRAINT PK_roomId PRIMARY KEY (hid, RoomNo)
); 

CREATE TABLE Booking (
gId int, 
hId int, 
RoomNo int, 
FromDate Date, 
ToDate Date,
PaymentMethod varchar(100),
FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hotel(hid),
FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES Guest(gid),
FOREIGN KEY (RoomNo) REFERENCES Room(RoomNo),
CONSTRAINT PK_bookingRoom PRIMARY KEY (gId, hId, RoomNo, FromDate)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to create the `Booking` table with foreign key references to the `Hotel`, `Guest`, and `Room` tables, but if you create `Booking` first, then those tables don't exist yet.

You need to create the other tables first, then create the `Booking` table that references them.

Or as an alternative, create `Booking`, but without declaring its foreign keys. Then create the other tables. Then use `ALTER TABLE Booking` to add foreign key constraints to that table.

However you do it, foreign keys can't reference a table before you create those tables.